# Sending "Auto-Accepted" Appointments using Exchange Web Services

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I need to send appointments/meetings to individual mailboxes from EWS that are auto accepted, right now I send the appointments and go back into each mailbox and accept them programmatically, cleaning up the responses and such, for the most part it works but I find it clunky.

Looking for a cleaner solution to this, I'm using Exchange Server 2007 SP1 with Exchange Web Services Managed API 1.1, C#..

Looking to see if anyone else has any suggestions or solutions to this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Think it would it be worth looking into incorporating a custom Exchange Transport Agent or event sink to accept these meetings?

Comment: This would only work if the OP can distinguish his meeting requests from any other. Otherwise, he would auto-accept all meetings and not only the ones he created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no better way.